# Формирование массива из данных

Tags: python, python-3.x

Данные выглядят так:

```
Gustman;82;95;40
Mercer;27;99;37
Gill;70;63;42
Hawkins;24;98;58
Hodges;39;63;99
Winter;94;68;82
Gerald;84;72;87
Bawerman;89;72;61
```

Нужно привести их к виду: [['Gustman','82','95','40'],['Mercer','27','99','37']...]

```
import re
with open('data.txt') as inf:
    data=[j for j in inf.read().split('\n')]
data
```

Вот мой код, как его доработать и где более подробно об этом прочитать?

Answer (score 2):

То что касается вашего кода, то решение добавить ещё один split(), только по символу ";". Получиться так:

```
with open('data.csv') as inf:
   data=[j.split(';') for j in inf.read().split('\n')]
print(data)
```

результат

```
[['Gustman', '82', '95', '40'], ['Mercer', '27', '99', '37'], ['Gill', '70', '63', '42'],... ]
```

Тут есть маленький нюанс. У вас в примере вывода в первом списке отсутствует значение '40', но во втором списке присутствует '37'. Там некая закономерность или просто очипятка?

Ну а в целом, Вы явно работаете с csv файлом, так что возможно пригодятся раздел документации про [работу CSV файлам](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: Все нормально, это опечатка)Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Как уже [сказал @ivan_susanin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/621301/211923) лучше воспользоваться модулем [CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

with open(r'C:\Temp\.data\621286.csv') as f:
     data = [row for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')]

print(data)
```

Результат:

```
[['Gustman', '82', '95', '40'], ['Mercer', '27', '99', '37'], ['Gill', '70', '63', '42'], ['Hawkins', '24', '98', '58'], ['Hodges', '39', '63', '99'],
 ['Winter', '94', '68', '82'], ['Gerald', '84', '72', '87'], ['Bawerman', '89', '72', '61']]
```

Если вы хотите дальше обрабатывать и/или анализировать эти данные, то очень советую обратить внимание на модуль [Pandas (Panel Data)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

Пример:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(fn, sep=';', header=None, names=['name','c1','c2','c3'])
```

DataFrame:

```
In [37]: df
Out[37]:
       name  c1  c2  c3
0   Gustman  82  95  40
1    Mercer  27  99  37
2      Gill  70  63  42
3   Hawkins  24  98  58
4    Hodges  39  63  99
5    Winter  94  68  82
6    Gerald  84  72  87
7  Bawerman  89  72  61
```

Среднее значение всех числовых столбцов:

```
In [38]: df.mean()
Out[38]:
c1    63.625
c2    78.750
c3    63.250
dtype: float64
```

А это структура, которая необходима вам:

```
In [39]: df.astype(str).values.tolist()
Out[39]:
[['Gustman', '82', '95', '40'],
 ['Mercer', '27', '99', '37'],
 ['Gill', '70', '63', '42'],
 ['Hawkins', '24', '98', '58'],
 ['Hodges', '39', '63', '99'],
 ['Winter', '94', '68', '82'],
 ['Gerald', '84', '72', '87'],
 ['Bawerman', '89', '72', '61']]
```